# Updating Database

Tags: c#, asp.net, ado.net, sql-server-express

So Visual Studio tells me that my quotes are not right in the update statement.  I feel it might be something more than that.  I feel I am close but I don't see where I am going wrong in this sql statement.  The point of the webpage is to update the database that is all for this step.  Can someone help me out.

Here is my code.

P.S. - I did an insert statement similar to this but the string idString part all the way to the softwareReportRecord.Close(); was beneath the update statement and it worked.

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        reportDateText.Text = DateTime.Today.ToShortDateString();
        //code page 429
        if (Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            Page.Validate();
            if (Page.IsValid)
            {

                bugReportForm.Visible = false;
                regMessage.Visible = true;
                string typeOS = oSListbox.SelectedValue;
                string reportDate = reportDateText.Text;
                string hardware = hardwareText.Text;
                string occurrence = occurrenceRadioButtonList.SelectedValue;
                string shortDescription = shortDescriptionText.Text;
                string longDescription = longDescriptionText.Text;
                string actionsTaken = actionsTakenText.Text;
                SqlConnection dbConnection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=true");
                try
                {
                    dbConnection.Open();
                    dbConnection.ChangeDatabase("BugsReport");

                }
                catch (SqlException exception)
                {
                    if (exception.Number == 911)
                    {
                        SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand("CREATE DATABASE BugsReport", dbConnection);
                        sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        regMessage.Text = "<p>Successfully created the database.</p>";
                        dbConnection.ChangeDatabase("BugsReport");
                    }
                    else
                        Response.Write("<p>Error code " + exception.Number
                            + ": " + exception.Message + "</p>");
                }
                finally
                {
                    regMessage.Text += "<p>Successfully selected the database.</p>";
                }
                try
                {
                    string SQLString = "SELECT * FROM softwareLog";
                    SqlCommand checkIDTable = new SqlCommand(SQLString, dbConnection);
                    SqlDataReader idRecords = checkIDTable.ExecuteReader();
                    idRecords.Close();
                }
                catch (SqlException exception)
                {
                    if (exception.Number == 208)
                    {
                        SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand("CREATE TABLE softwareLog (reportID SMALLINT IDENTITY(100,1) PRIMARY KEY, typeOS VARCHAR(25), reportDate DATE, hardware VARCHAR(50), occurrence VARCHAR(15), shortDescription VARCHAR(100), longDescription VARCHAR(500), actionsTaken VARCHAR(25))", dbConnection);
                        sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        regMessage.Text += "<p>Successfully created the table.</p>";
                    }
                    else
                        regMessage.Text += "<p>Error code " + exception.Number
                            + ": " + exception.Message + "</p>";
                }
                finally
                {
                    string idString = "SELECT IDENT_CURRENT('softwareLog') AS reportID";
                SqlCommand newID = new SqlCommand(idString, dbConnection);
                SqlDataReader softwareReportRecord = newID.ExecuteReader();
                softwareReportRecord.Read();
                string reportID = Convert.ToString(softwareReportRecord["reportID"]);
                softwareReportRecord.Close();

                string editRecord = "UPDATE softwareLog SET "
            + "typeOS='" + typeOS + "', "
            + "reportDate='" + reportDate + "', "
            + "hardware='" + hardware + "' "
            + "occurrence='" + occurrence + "' "
            + "shortDescription='" + shortDescription + "' "
            + "longDescription='" + longDescription + "' "
            + "actionsTaken='" + actionsTaken + "' "
            + "WHERE reportID=" + reportID + ";";



                    SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(editRecord, dbConnection);
                    sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }


                dbConnection.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}




finally
                {
                    string addRecord = "INSERT INTO softwareLog VALUES('"
                        + typeOS + "', '"
                        + reportDate + "', '"
                        + hardware + "', '"
                        + occurrence + "', '"
                        + shortDescription + "', '"
                        + longDescription + "', '"
                        + actionsTaken + "')";

                    SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(addRecord, dbConnection);
                    sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
                string idString = "SELECT IDENT_CURRENT('softwareLog') AS reportID";
                SqlCommand newID = new SqlCommand(idString, dbConnection);
                SqlDataReader softwareReportRecord = newID.ExecuteReader();
                softwareReportRecord.Read();
                string reportID = Convert.ToString(softwareReportRecord["reportID"]);
                softwareReportRecord.Close();
                regMessage.Text += "<p>Sorry for your inconvience. We will be working on your problem ASAP.  For reference your ID is  </p>" + reportID;

                dbConnection.Close();
```

Comment: Run it on debug Mode and See the value of Edit Record with help of Break Point. and try to run that from sql management studio. You will know where is the problem.

Comment: Tell us where you stuck?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements (especially `INSERT` or `UPDATE`) - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing too many "," in Update. 
**EDIT**   You have single quote inside string. You need to escape those quotes also:

```
string editRecord = "UPDATE softwareLog SET "
    + "typeOS='" + typeOS.Replace("'", "''") + "', "
    + "reportDate='" + reportDate + "', "
    + "hardware='" + hardware.Replace("'", "''") + "',"
    + "occurrence='" + occurrence.Replace("'", "''") + "',"
    + "shortDescription='" + shortDescription.Replace("'", "''") + "',"
    + "longDescription='" + longDescription + "',"
    + "actionsTaken='" + actionsTaken.Replace("'", "''") + "'"
    + "WHERE reportID= " + reportID ;
```

In insert you don't need quote for reportID:

```
string addRecord = "INSERT INTO softwareLog VALUES('"
    + typeOS.Replace("'", "''") + "', '"
    + reportDate + "', '"
    + hardware.Replace("'", "''") + "', '"
    + occurrence.Replace("'", "''") + "', '"
    + shortDescription.Replace("'", "''") + "', '"
    + longDescription.Replace("'", "''") + "', '"
    + actionsTaken.Replace("'", "''") + "')";
```

Comment: That and he should really be using parameters... or better yet, a stored procedure.

Comment: I copied that code over and get the same error anyway to show me how a better way.  We aren't to stored procedures in this class yet.  I know of them but we arent too them.

Comment: Still the same error.  If there is a better way to do this be my guest.  It should work.

Comment: There's one thing I can think of, ReportID could be null. Can you please confirm it?

Comment: Or You can try replacing null with 0 like, as I have shown in my post.

Comment: Is it possible to upload a zip file so you could look at it? would that be easier?

Comment: Upload the file in goole drive. right click the file and select share-->Email as attachment.

Comment: Ok you will have an email shortly

Comment: Ok sent you should have an email

Comment: So how would the delete go then ....also i noticed that the update updated BOTH records is there a way to fix that

Comment: Forgot to remove quote from reportID variable... fixed it!

Comment: Sweet I see what you did ....So how would would i redirect to a page. Also i have a delete statement that doesnt seem to work maybe you can help me                                                          string editRecord = "DELETE FROM softwareLog WHERE reportID=" + idString;

Comment: Probably you would like to see what you are deleting before it is gone!I will email you back with some suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Chances are the data being passed to the query be terminating the string early.  For many reasons (including this one, but also SQL injection), you should be using parameters instead of concatenation.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this,

```
 string editRecord = "UPDATE softwareLog SET "
          + "typeOS='" + typeOS + "', "
          + "reportDate='" + reportDate + "', "
          + "hardware='" + hardware + "',"
          + "occurrence='" + occurrence + "',"
          + "shortDescription='" + shortDescription + "',"
          + "longDescription='" + longDescription + "',"
          + "actionsTaken='" + actionsTaken + "'"
          + "WHERE reportID=" + reportID + "";
```

Can you please Add your Insert Statement too.

> **Remarks** : It will better to use Parametrized SqlCommand or Store
>   Procedure to perform this type of operation.

If you supply value with ' to any field then, it will not work. Also check value you supply for ReportId.

Comment: That is wrong. The last "," before WHERE will cause an error.

Comment: If there are 7th Column in your Table softwareLog and All field are text type like Varchar, Nvarchar etc. Then your insert operation will work. Is there any problem in insert Operation.

Comment: No for some reason it still throwing fits.  This is what I get   Incorrect syntax near 't'.

Answer (score 0):

In this example you should be using parameters as a precaution against SQL injection as others have mentioned.

But for other strings I suggest you look into string.Format() rather than concatenating everything. Would make that string so much easier to read.